# Loading External Swfs in Adobe Air

Tags: flash, air, loading, sandbox

Can anybody help me on how to load external swf's in adobe air.

Every time i try i get a security sandbox violation message.

Can anybody help me with this

Answer (score 0):

check this Lynda.com AIR 2 with Flash and Flex Essential Training
http://www.lynda.com/home/DisplayCourseNoTabs.aspx?lpk2=68629